# INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER - filename not found in Content-Disposition header of multipart form

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to add a document by multipart form to an existing draft envelope via the Docusign REST API endpoint: `/envelopes/[envelopeId]/documents/[documentId]`

The error message I get is:

```
The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A filename was not 
found in the Content-Disposition header ('filename="filename.ext"
```

As you can see, there is a filename parameter in the Content-Disposition value. I've tried multiple different edits and adjustments of the Content-Disposition header, but each has failed. Here is what appears to be the correct format that throws the error.

```
Headers:
Authorization "Bearer [token]"
Accept "application/json"
Content-Type "multipart/form-data; boundary=AAAAAA"

--AAAAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/json

{"fileExtension":"pdf","name":"test file name.pdf","documentId":1,"order":1}
--AAAAAA
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test file name.pdf"; documentId=1
Content-Type: application/pdf

[binary output]
--AAAAAA--
```

Anyone from Docusign or in general able to see what's wrong or give me a hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multipart/form-data will not work for the [updateEnvelopeDocument](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update/) api

Instead specify the `Content-Type` and `content-disposition` in the Headers. Request body should only contain the file stream.

> put /envelopes/[envelopeId]/documents/[documentId]

[Headers]

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
content-disposition: file; filename="test file name.pdf"; fileExtension=pdf; documentId=1
```

[Body]

[binary output]

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use the [updateListEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList/) api which supports `multipart/form-data`. You can also choose to update multiple documents in a single api call using this api.

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents

Headers:
Authorization "Bearer [token]"
Accept "application/json"
Content-Type "multipart/form-data; boundary=AAAAAA"

--AAAAAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": 1,
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "test file name.pdf"
        }
    ]
}

--AAAAAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test file name.pdf"; fileExtension=pdf; documentId=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: stream

[Binary output]

--AAAAAA--
```

Comment: can we use update document call with a sent envelope where signing ceremony has not started till now, I can see Web Console allows to update the document retaining all the tags. But on doing update using this call, I could update the document but lose all the tags which were present on the initial document.